# mediaelement.js audio doubling up in IE7/8

Tags: jquery, audio, mediaelement.js, mediaelement

I'm using http://mediaelementjs.com to load in audio and video on a project I'm working on. It works flawlessly on newer browsers.

The main feature I need from it (other than cross browser audio/video support) is the on ended callback when audio clips finish.

Everything loads in IE7/8, but the audio is doubling (tippling/quadrupling) up on itself. It's an eerie effect.

I'm loading it like this:

```
function play1(){
    var audioPlayer = MediaElement('player1', {
          success: function (media) {
              media.play();
              media.addEventListener('ended', function (e) {
                  setTimeout(function(){
                              play2();
                  }, 2000);
              }, false);
          };
    });
};
```

the next audio clip play2() loads on ended, which is set up much like the function above. For some reason, in IE7/8 it loads the audio consecutive times.

I though perhaps I could make audioPlayer a global variable and it would overwrite the audio each time, but that didn't work.

Comment: function play1 is not syntactically correct.

Comment: Thanks Ricardus, you're talking about the extra }; after play();? That was an error on my part when posting. It's correct in the real function. I'll edit it here.

Answer (score 0):

With this version of function **play1** mediaelement.js loads successfully:

```
function play1(){
    var audioPlayer = MediaElementPlayer('#player1', {
          success: function (media) {
              media.play();
              media.addEventListener('ended', function (e) {
                  setTimeout(function(){
                              play2();
                  }, 2000);
              }, false);
          }
    });
}
```

Which js and css of the mediaelement.js library do you insert in the head section of your document?
Try adding the following line in the beginning of the **ended event listener** in order to force the first audio to pause:

```
media.pause();
```

If that doesn't work, try destroying the first audio object or your HTML container provided that you don't need it for future reference.
This may seem an overkill though.